# Do I work with the files in the working git copy?

Tags: git

I am new to git. Before git I have used svn.
I have read a lots of stuff about git, but there are some points I don't understand. 
I use Eclipse and Egit.

So let me begin to describe.
Do I need a copy of the files in the working copy of the cloned repository, or can i directly work with them? How can I add the files in a projekt? I've tried in Eclipse Import -> Projects from Git -> URI an local and so on. But my Project stays empty. There are only `.config-files`.

Comment: I would clone them, since the paradigm behind git is that of a distributed VCS.  Plus it would certainly be more practical to have the files saved locally.

Comment: Do you mean, you clone the working copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, every "repo" is also a "working directory". You might want to designate a "master" and only use it for cloning and merging, but this is up to you.

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand it more and more.